# Magento 2 inline translation not working

Tags: magento2, inline-translations

I am trying to use inline translations on Magento 2. Already when I open the translastion I see a weird screen. 
[image]

When I resize the screen it becomes more clear.

[image]

but then comes the weird part, I add the translation and I see on screen that it's translated. When I refresh it's gone again.

I already cleared all cache / static content / redeployed / added the inline translate flag only on store level etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have recently experienced this issue myself on Magento 2.2.5. After clicking 'Submit' nothing is actually updated on the frontend. I have of course tried clearing all caches and made sure that I was was on correct store view when enabling 'Translate Inline'. Did you ever figure this out by any chance?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141063)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141063)

Comment: Same here, any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Updating question to help those facing the same.

That's a Chrome issue. Happens very often.
When it occurs, close the page and start all over. The changes will be saved after clearing Magento Cache. Sometimes it is also good to clear Chrome browser history.

Hope that helps